# Keep vertical scroll position after submit

Tags: jquery, scroll

I can't make this work. I made a very simple script in AJAX for a form which is very long. So the user can save his settings without reloading the whole page.

It works pretty fine but the window just goes to the top of the page after submit, is there a jQuery way to prevent this?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you have `action='#'` set for the form and you are not returning `false` from your submit handler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `#` with `javascript:void(0)`. This will prevent the browser from scrolling to the top. This is probably in a HTML `action` or `href` attribute.

**EDIT**

And if you insist on a jQuery solution...

```
action="javascript:$.noop()"
```